# Why does Windows Firewall want to block Google Chrome today?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, windows-firewall

I've been using the same public Wi-Fi (staying in a guesthouse) for over a week now.

But this morning for the first time I got this puzzling warning from Windows Firewall:

[image: Windows Firewall has blocked some features of Google Chrome on all public and private networks]

Why does Windows Firewall want to block one of the world's most popular web browsers today after being fine with it for years, and being fine with it on this connection for a week?

Could it hinge on the words, ***some features***? If so could it be something like a rare or new feature of Chrome that uses a different HTTP port? And if so why doesn't the security alert tell me any more about it?

Or could it be a known bug in Windows Firewall?
Or perhaps a known virus etc attaching itself to Google Chrome?
Or is there a chance it's related to ["Other browser makers follow Google's lead, revoke rogue certificates"](http://www.computerworld.com/s/article/9244645/Other_browser_makers_follow_Google_s_lead_revoke_rogue_certificates)?

I haven't restarted Chrome for days and have downloaded but not installed a Windows update from a few days ago. So I'm not sure what may have managed to change on my machine since yesterday.

Comment: I think the reason behind this is a toolbar or an addon within chrome...

Comment: Hmm I loathe toolbars and abhor addons. I've judiciously installed (or coded) a few but none of them have been updated since yesterday when I used Chrome without getting such a warning.

Comment: Because Microsoft likes to push their own useless browser(IE), I got the same thing when trying to install Firefox.

Comment: @Slowki Please don't make up reasons that don't exist. This has nothing at all to do with pushing IE (which is also far from 'useless' in its latest iterations, but I digress).

Comment: @Bob it obviously wasn't a serious statement(Although after doing web developing I have learned to hate IE) the point was that it's basically all conjecture in this case. The most likely concept I've come across in my research is that Windows' firewall simply doesn't like things that have the level of access to the internet that browsers tend to have.

Comment: Its simple.  Windows is not trying to block anything it allowing you to provide permission for Chrome to access the internet.  Has the reason this prompt wasn't offered to you a week ago, only you can tell us that, there is likely something that has changed ( you are just not aware of it ).

Comment: @Slowki - This permission prompt would be given to any application.  Microsoft's software included.

Comment: This prompt only appears the first time an application is trying to *listen for connections*. That’s not what a web browser is supposed to do.

Answer (score 1):

Google Chrome updates itself without asking you first (Firefox does the same - nothing sinister, just makes sure you always have the latest security patches), and this is separate from Windows Update. Since you're on public wifi, Windows Firewall is stricter about changes to network-accessing software than it would be on a network you marked as private.

Comment: Google Chrome downloads its new updates in the background but it shows a coloured symbol to let you know that it's out of date and only actually starts running the new version when you restart. I've typically got many tabs open and only sporadic Internet access so I only restart Chrome when I specifically get the time and connectivity to do it properly. (I'm hitchhiking in China.) I have now restarted a few times since asking this question but not at the time. I haven't seen this happen again though.

Answer (score 0):

Google Chrome opens an exception TO the Internet, but also opens and exception FROM the Internet - allowing it an open door to your system.  Blocking this feature by unchecking the exception is what I do, or not allowing it to make the exception in the first place.

Comment: "opens an exception from the Internet". Wrong. You'll need to setup NAT on your Internet router/firewall for that to happen